# What was the significance of these kids, if any?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, runaways, runaways-2017

At the beginning of *Runaways* season 2, the parents are called by the police, who have supposedly found their kids. Of course, it's the wrong group.

However, this other group of children is *extremely* similar to the Runaways in appearance: a Latina girl who looks vaguely like Molly with a very similar pink hat, a European-American looking girl with purple-dyed hair (and what looks like the sort of gender equality activism T-shirt Gertrude might wear, and an *iguana*), a blond girl...etc. It's not just down to number, gender, and ethnicity, but hairstyles, clothing, apparent interests! It's not presented as a joke, either, as one would expect, but with dramatic music and framing.

Was this just a one-off joke or was there more to it?